# Rails SQL Where If condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, where-clause

I am trying to create an advanced search form for a rails blog
I'm trying to avoid using a gem
I have a table `posts` with a `title`, `location_id` and `category_id`, the last two are connected to two tables Location (:small, :greater) and Category (name), but I doubt that's important for this question

I have a search form which finds all posts where location_id and category_id is equal to the user set option

```
<%= form_for(@advanced_search) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :category_search %><br>
   <%= f.collection_select :category_search, Category.all, :id, :name, :
include_blank => "any category" %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :location_search %><br>
   <%= f.collection_select :location_search, Location.all, :id, :locationsmallgreat
,:include_blank => "any city" %>  

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Once again i doubt that's important for the question which is probably simpler than I'm explaining it to be

Basically I have this so far

```
@posts = Post.all
         @posts = @posts.where('category_id = ?', @advanced_search.category_search) if @advanced_search.category_search != "any category"
         @posts = @posts.where('location_id = ?', @advanced_search.location_search) if @advanced_search.location_search != "any city"
```

But it doesn't seem to work 
I need it to work as so, If the form has Category = Any category (:included_blank => "any category)
and Location = London 
It would search for all Posts where location is == london, BUT it would remove the .where for the category, seeing that it is == any city and vice versa if a Category was selected and Location was left blank (:included_blank => "any city)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if @advanced_search.category_search.present? && @advanced_search.location_search.present?
  Post.
    where('category_id = ?', @advanced_search.category_search).
    where('location_id = ?', @advanced_search.location_search).
    all
elsif @advanced_search.category_search.present?
  Post.
    where('category_id = ?', @advanced_search.category_search).
    all
elsif @advanced_search.location_search.present?
  Post.
    where('location_id = ?', @advanced_search.location_search).
    all
else
  Post.all
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this seems to only show all posts and not filter

Comment: do you have `any_location` stored in your DB as `location_id`

Comment: "any location (city)" is just text in the form collection_select box to have a blank option `<%= f.collection_select :location_search, Location.all, :id, :small,:include_blank => "any city" %> `

Comment: So I tried it again and I was still getting all posts, but then I thought that maybe it was because it wasn't recognising "any city" and/or "any category". I selected any city and used this in my show.html.erb `<% if @advanced_search.location_search == "any city" %><h1>HELLO</h1><% end %>` and of course, It didnt print Hello, so it leads me to conclude that maybe rails isn't registering "any city". I tried changing  != "any city" and  != "any category" in your answer to .blank? but still it would only display All posts. Thoughts?

Comment: I sincerely don't know what `@advanced_search` is, you probably want to log it, and see what rails is returning in the logs

Comment: I got it working with this `@posts = Post.all
    @posts = @posts.where('category_id = ?', @advanced_search.category_search) if @advanced_search.category_search.present?
    @posts = @posts.where('location_id = ?', @advanced_search.location_search) if @advanced_search.location_search.present?
    `

Comment: if you want to edit your answer to the above I wouldn't mind checking it green

Comment: I have modified with `present?` instead of checking against a value, which I think might be more efficient than your option